# Solution of the following equation: $ (x-y)(2dy-dx)=3dx-5dy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When rearranged, I got: $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{3-y+x}{2x-2y+5}$. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

**hint**:Put $u = y-x \implies y' = (u+x)' = u'+1 \implies u'+1 = \dfrac{3-u}{5-2u}$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Start defining $$2x-2y+5=z \implies y=\frac{1}{2} (2 x-z+5)\implies y'=\frac{1}{2} \left(2-z'\right)$$ The equation becomes $$z'+\frac{1}{z}=1$$ which looks to be separable.